# Wrong css informations by using window.getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this html code

```
<div id="testdiv3" style="border-left: 2px solid green; border-top: 4px dashed red; border-bottom: 3px dotted blue;">testcontent</div>
```

For the testdiv above, I see these styles in the console/styles

```
Element {
    border-left: 2px solid green;
    border-top: 4px dashed red;
    border-bottom: 3px dotted blue;
}
```

so it is, and so it should be noticed in the data which I have to use in jquery.

in my jscode, I catch the css-styles by using

```
...window.getComputedStyle...
```

so far so good.

Now in my testcase I see a situation I don't understand and therefore I have to create a way to prevent it.

In contrast to the shown css-styles in the console I received this in jquery/jscode

```
"Object { style_name: "border-bottom-color", style_value: "rgb(0, 0, 255)", style_unit: null }
​"Object { style_name: "border-left-color", style_value: "rgb(0, 128, 0)", style_unit: null }
"Object { style_name: "border-right-color", style_value: "rgb(71, 76, 80)", style_unit: null }
"Object { style_name: "border-top-color", style_value: "rgb(255, 0, 0)", style_unit: null }​
```

even though the "bottom-top-right" is not set to a border color, I received a border color. Why?

I think the color is from the body, in his css is a color defined "color #474c50" what matched the "rgb(71, 76, 80)"...

**So how can I either prevent that there will return a css-style which is not for this css-kind (which is not really in use) or how can I check if this style is an "own" style or a kind of inherited style?**

Additional to this, an inherited style, will use active for the style the page. This style is not in use, so I cannot understand why it will be returned.

Hope somebody could help me with this (and I hope I could explain it to understand what's my situation and needs).

thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not wrong at all. It's because all elements have default styling applied to them. That's what's being returned from your call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the console of http://jsfiddle.net/ydrsx4jc/2/
It should explain a lot.

To bring it on the point:
Each DOM element has default attributes.
These attributes are controlable with css.

Even if you set the `border` attribute for one side to `none` html will set the `border` to it's "default" value.

You could say: If you are using only three sides of the `border` you are using the fourth, too. Even if you don't want to and even if you don't see it.

Comment: so you meas, there is no other way as check if a border-width is set to check if color is needed?

Comment: Working with computed styles will always return a value. Check if element.style.borderLeftColor might return a different result.

Answer (score 0):

The computed value is indeed this value because all CSS rules have default values <sub>[citation needed]</sub>, set by the browser itself if you don't set it (a.k.a *user agent rules*) and that the one of `border-[]-color` rules is `currentColor` which when serialized must return the serialization of element's active `color` rule.

It can indeed be the one of the body if your element only inherits its `color` from there.

But if you set its `color` to some other value, then this value will be used.

And to your case, maybe you will rather want to check the `width` and `style` values instead.

```js
const computed = getComputedStyle(el);
console.log(computed['border-right-color']); // rgb(255, 165, 0)
console.log(computed['border-right-style']); // none
console.log(computed['border-right-width']); // 0px
```

```css
#el {
    border-left: 2px solid green;
    border-top: 4px dashed red;
    border-bottom: 3px dotted blue;
    /* defaults: */
    /* border-right: 0px none currentColor; */
    color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note getComputedStyle(el) return value in px**

if you want to change other measurement like pt,mm,in,%,em

**Convert Your value like**

pt = 3/4*px

em = pt/12

% = pt*100/12